# Get SQL Computed Column Inserted Value

Tags: sql-server, calculated-columns, sql-function, autogeneratecolumn

My Table Structure as follow,

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_Info
(
    [SSEID]         BIGINT              NOT NULL    IDENTITY(1,1),
    [ShortenKey]    AS ConvertToBase([SSEID]),
    [Title]         VARCHAR(500)        NULL,       
)
```

`ConvertToBase` Function as Follow,

```
CREATE FUNCTION ConvertToBase(@Number BIGINT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(15)
AS 
BEGIN
      // implementation
END
```

I need to get the generated [ShortenKey] value after INSERT query in sp. how to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [OUTPUT clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)?

```
INSERT tbl_Info (Title)
OUTPUT INSERTED.ShortenKey
VALUES ('new title')
```

Note: may not work with computed columns says MSDN, if I read it correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this error..."Column 'inserted.ShortenKey' cannot be referenced in the OUTPUT clause because the column definition contains a subquery or references a function that performs user or system data access. A function is assumed by default to perform data access if it is not schemabound. Consider removing the subquery or function from the column definition or removing the column from the OUTPUT clause.
"

Comment: Add WITH SCHEMABINDING to the fucntion

Answer (score 1):

Use `SCOPE_IDENTITY` to get the new identity value. Then query the newly inserted row.

```
SELECT ShortenKey
FROM dbo.tbl_Info
WHERE SSEID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Comment: @gbn My code sample returns ShortenKey. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ShortenKey
FROM dbo.tbl_Info
WHERE SSEID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```